# What's the solution to this exponential system of equation?

Tags: exponentiation, systems-of-equations

What are the steps to solving a system of equations when $x$ and $y$ are exponents? But they have different base. Here is the problem.

$5^x\times3^y=45$

$3^x\times5^y=75$

Comment: Multiply the two euqtions: You get a value for $x+y$. Divide the two equations, you get a value for $x-y$

Comment: What should I multiply with to get the value of $x+y$?

Comment: Multiply the first equation to the second equation.

Comment: Super thank you voldemort and @kyson, I found the solution. I got $x=1$ and $y=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take log.

$$x\log5+y\log3=\log45$$

$$x\log3+y\log5=\log75$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still confuse how to find the value of $x$ and $y$.
Since the $x$ and $y$ are the power for different number, I can't manipulate them.

And after taking logarithm, though, it couldn't help me yet.

Comment: Do you know how to solve simultaneous linear equations? Otherwise, you can follow voldmort's method.

Comment: I know how to solve simultaneous linear equations. But I don't know how to modify these equations as they have logarithm in it. 

And, what is voldmort's method?

Comment: The method suggested by voldmort in his comment on your post.

Comment: If you know how to simultaneous linear equations, then you should be able to solve the equations in the answer I posted. It's just two simultaneous linear equations. The coefficients are logarithms though. But logarithms are just numbers.